# Create a View for my list

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2010

I have a quick question. 
I have a custom list, and i wanted to create views of this lists. To do that, i've created view nodes in the  of the Schema.xml of the list.

```
 <Views>
      <View Name="{53EB3C9C-A765-4629-A938-7B912E04083B}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="Tous les éléments" Url="/circulationaccords/Lists/FicheAccord/AllItems.aspx"  BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
        </ViewFields>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
      </View>
      <View Name="{7AB6A3F1-E8A4-49D7-9B95-BFC9DE7D52A9}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="ParDateDeDemande" Url="/circulationaccords/Lists/FicheAccord/ParDateDeDemande.aspx"  BaseViewID="2" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
        <Query>
          <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30">
            <FieldRef Name="DateDemande"/>
          </GroupBy>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="DateDemande"/>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
          <FieldRef Name="EtapeEnCours"/>
          <FieldRef Name="IdentiteFournisseur"/>
          <FieldRef Name="NomEtablissement"/>
          <FieldRef Name="NomDemandeur"/>
          <FieldRef Name="ObjetCommande"/>
          <FieldRef Name="StatutDemande"/>
          <FieldRef Name="ActeurEnCours"/>
          <FieldRef Name="DateDemande"/>
        </ViewFields>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
      </View>
    </Views>
```

The problem here is that views are not created, but when i go into the list parameters to see views, i see the views as model of views. I would like to directly get the views.

Does someone have any idea how this could work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the attributes your View elements like this:

```
<View 
    DefaultView="TRUE"
    MobileView="TRUE"
    MobileDefaultView="TRUE"
    Type="HTML"
    DisplayName="Tous les éléments"
    Url="AllItems.aspx"
    BaseViewID="1"
    SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
<View 
    MobileView="TRUE"
    Type="HTML"
    DisplayName="ParDateDeDemande"
    Url="ParDateDeDemande.aspx"
    BaseViewID="2"
    SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
```

I think the absence of the SetupPath attribute and an overly specific Url attribute might be the reason your views are not displaying as expected.

Comment: It still doesn't work,
I added the WebPartZoneID="Main" to see if that was the problem, but still doesn't work neither. I just don't get it, it's not supposed to be hard to create views in SharePoint is it ?

Comment: No, it isn't hard to create views. I've done it many times using something similar to what I have above. After changing schema.xml, did you do the following: 1) deactivate/activate the feature on the site and 2) create a new list instance from your list definition? Changing the schema.xml will have no effect on existing lists and redeploying the feature definition might not work within a site unless that version has been activated.

Comment: I've just tried by deleting the site collection, and the solution, and deploying everything again, and it still doesn't work ... 
The weird thing is that it works good with another custom list i have ... -_-

Comment: ok, i've just deleted the list, and reactivated the feature, and it worked. I guess deleting the site collection wasn't enough, i had to delete the web Application ? 

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: In fact, I've tried to delete everything : Site collection, Solution, and Web Application, and it didn't worked as i expected. It seems that i have to delete the list manually and reactivate the feature so that it works ... 
Do you have any idea where it could possibly come from ?

Comment: You definitely should not have to delete the Web Application. And deleting the site collection should definitely clear it out. The way you are getting it to work makes me think there is something strange either in your feature or in the order of how features are activated in order to automatically create the list with in the site collection. Now that you have something that works manually, you need to carefully inspect the order and method of how features are activated during the provisioning of the site to get the same behavior automatically.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer again, 
I've finally turned the server off and on again, and it worked. Don't ask me why and how, but now it works, Sometimes i prefer not asking myself too much questions. 
Thanks a lot for your help though